# Read/Write to a Local XML File in Android

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and relatively new to Java so please bear with me. I have an XML file stored in the res/xml that I am trying to write to. I know how to read it using XmlResourceParser, but I have not been able to find a way to write to that file locally. Could someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Do you mean you have that XML file in your source code tree and you are trying to modify it from your application ?

Comment: yes. exactly. is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: You can't. The resources of your app are static and can not be modified. You will have to write a new XML file to the SD card or to the internal memory for this.

Comment: Ahh, I figured as much but I thought I would ask. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your application dynamic by creating a new XML file and writing the same to the internal memory that you use for this.